# Python: Opening process on a certain screen

Tags: python, internet-explorer, popen

I wrote a script for myself so when I login to the computer 4 IE windows auto start. I tried to use the webbrowser module but it would load the 4 links into 1 IE window with tabs. I could not get webbrowser to open 4 different windows so I used subprocess.Popen.

I have 4 monitors and I want each instance of IE to automatically start on the appropriate screen. Right now I can only get the 4 windows to load behind eachother on the main screen. How can I accomplish this? I have googled and googled and I cannot find anything about opening the process with certain dimensions or on a certain screen... Here is my script:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" hxxps://myserver.com/Orion/SummaryView.aspx?viewid=1')

subprocess.Popen('"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" hxxp://myserver2.com:8080/WOListView.do')

subprocess.Popen('"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" hxxp://myserver3.com:8888/stats/cgi?sid=301960859109&area=stats&action=noc&id=22689236889&page=22&sel=tab_listview_sel_22689236889')

subprocess.Popen('"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" hxxps://mymail.com/owa/')
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can do this with Python standard cross-platform functions alone. Using Windows API you can specify application window starting position and size with `dwX`, `dwY`, `dwXSize`, `dwYSize` members of the `STARTUPINFO` structure passed to the `CreateProcess` function. There are probably examples out there of using `CreateProcess` with Python `ctypes` FFI facility. Multi-monitor setup essentially provides one big virtual desktop with continuous coordinate system, so by setting these parameters you can make each window to appear on a separate monitor. Again, you need Windows API to determine coordinates of each monitor inside this big virtual screen space, namely `EnumDisplayMonitors` and `GetMonitorInfo` functions. Or, since you are probably never going to use it on any other machine, you can determine screen offsets experimentally and hardcode them.

Comment: Is there any documentation you would recommend on Windows API and python? I have been studying Python for 6 weeks and have no previous programming experience.

Comment: I have yet to find any good documentation on using win32 API in python. If anyone has anything I would appreciate it!